# Execute method on startup in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Is there any Spring 3 feature to execute some methods when the application starts for the first time? I know that I can do the trick of setting a method with `@Scheduled` annotation and it executes just after the startup, but then it will execute periodically.

Comment: what's the trick with @Scheduled? that's exactly what i want!

Answer (score 213, accepted):

If by "application startup" you mean "application context startup", then yes, there are [many ways to do this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle), the easiest (for singletons beans, anyway) being to annotate your method with `@PostConstruct`. Take a look at the link to see the other options, but in summary they are:

- Methods annotated with `@PostConstruct`
- `afterPropertiesSet()` as defined by the `InitializingBean` callback interface
- A custom configured init() method

Technically, these are hooks into the *bean* lifecycle, rather than the context lifecycle, but in 99% of cases, the two are equivalent.

If you need to hook specifically into the context startup/shutdown, then you can [implement the `Lifecycle` interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor) instead, but that's probably unnecessary.

Comment: I have yet to see an implementation of Lifecycle or SmartLifecycle after quite a bit of research. I know this is a year old, but skaffman if you have anything you can post that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The methods above get invoked before the entire application context has been created (eg. /before/ transaction demarcation has been setup).

Comment: I get a strange warning trying to use @PostConstruct in java 1.8: `Access restriction: The type PostConstruct is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar`

Comment: There are important cases where _bean_ and _context_ lifecycle are very different. As @HansWesterbeek noted a bean can be setup before the context it depends on is fully ready. In my situation a bean depended on JMS - it was fully constructed, so its `@PostConstruct` method was called, but the JMS infra-structure it indirectly depended on was not yet fully wired up (and being Spring everything just silently failed). On switching to `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` everything worked (`ApplicationReadyEvent` is Spring Boot specific for vanilla Spring see Stefan's answer).

Answer (score 116):

This is easily done with an `ApplicationListener`. I got this to work listening to Spring's `ContextRefreshedEvent`:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StartupHousekeeper implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    // do whatever you need here 
  }
}
```

Application listeners run synchronously in Spring. If you want to make sure you're code is executed only once, just keep some state in your component.

**UPDATE**

Starting with Spring 4.2+ you can also use the `@EventListener` annotation to observe the `ContextRefreshedEvent` (thanks to [@bphilipnyc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40414872/287138) for pointing this out):

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StartupHousekeeper {

  @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
  public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
    // do whatever you need here 
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too - perfect for one-time non-bean initialisation.

Comment: N.B. for those tempted to use `ContextStartedEvent` instead, it's harder to add the listener before the event fires.

Comment: Howto call an @Autowired JPA repositopry into event? the repository is null.

Comment: Not working for me. I am using spring mvc 3. This mehod onApplicationEvent(___) does not get called when application starts. Any help. Here is my code
@Component
public class AppStartListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

   public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
     System.out.println("\n\n\nInside on application event");
   }
 }

Comment: @VishwasTyagi How do you start your container? Are you sure, your AppStartListener is part of your component scan?

Comment: There are some more variations of the ContextRefreshedEvent in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409605/calling-a-method-after-all-springbeans-and-applicationcontext-have-been-initiali

Comment: Is it guaranteed that this listener invokes only once after startup?

Comment: I am using the updated version, it works. However, my debug break points aren't being caught. Any advice ?

Answer (score 41):

In Spring 4.2+ you can now simply do:

```
@Component
class StartupHousekeeper {

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that this listener invokes only once after startup?

Comment: No, see my answer above. Keep some state in your listener to check if it is executing for the first time

Answer (score 20):

With SpringBoot, we can execute a method on startup via `@EventListener` annotation

```
@Component
public class LoadDataOnStartUp
{   
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void loadData()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using spring-boot, this is the best answer.

I feel that `@PostConstruct` and other various life cycle interjections are round-about ways. These can lead directly to runtime issues or cause less than obvious defects due to unexpected bean/context lifecycle events. Why not just directly invoke your bean using plain Java? You still invoke the bean the 'spring way' (eg: through the spring AoP proxy). And best of all, it's plain java, can't get any simpler than that. No need for context listeners or odd schedulers.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        MyBean myBean = (MyBean)app.getBean("myBean");

        myBean.invokeMyEntryPoint();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea in general but when starting up your spring application context from a integration test, main is never run!

Comment: @JonasGeiregat: Plus, there are other scenarios where there is no `main()` at all, for example when using an application framework (e.g. JavaServer Faces).

Answer (score 10):

For Java 1.8 users that are getting a warning when trying to reference the @PostConstruct annotation, I ended up instead piggybacking off the @Scheduled annotation which you can do if you already have an @Scheduled job with fixedRate or fixedDelay.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

private static boolean needToRunStartupMethod = true;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
    public void keepAlive() {
        //log "alive" every hour for sanity checks
        LOGGER.debug("alive");
        if (needToRunStartupMethod) {
            runOnceOnlyOnStartup();
            needToRunStartupMethod = false;
        }
    }

    public void runOnceOnlyOnStartup() {
        LOGGER.debug("running startup job");
    }

}
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564361/scheduling-tasks-to-run-once-using-the-spring-task-namespace

Answer (score 6):

What we have done was extending `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` to print something when the context starts.

```
public class ContextLoaderListener extends org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ContextLoaderListener.class );

    public ContextLoaderListener()
    {
        logger.info( "Starting application..." );
    }
}
```

Configure the subclass then in `web.xml`:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.mycomp.myapp.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Attention, this is only advised if your `runOnceOnStartup` method depends on a
>   fully initialized spring context. For example: you wan to call a dao
>   with transaction demarcation

You can also use a scheduled method with fixedDelay set very high

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = Long.MAX_VALUE)
public void runOnceOnStartup() {
    dosomething();
}
```

This has the advantage that the whole application is wired up (Transactions, Dao, ...)

seen in [Scheduling tasks to run once, using the Spring task namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564361/scheduling-tasks-to-run-once-using-the-spring-task-namespace)

Comment: I don't see any advantage over using `@PostConstruct` ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe depends on what you want to do in dosomething()
calling an Autowired dao with Trasaction demarcation needs the whole context to be started up, not just this bean

Comment: @WimDeblauwe '@PostConstruct' method fires when the bean is initialized, the whole context might not be ready (fe Transaction management)

Comment: This is more elegant imo than post construct or any interfaces or events

Answer (score 2):

```
AppStartListener implements ApplicationListener {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if(event instanceof ApplicationReadyEvent){
            System.out.print("ciao");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ApplicationReadyEvent is in spring boot not in spring 3

Answer (score 1):

Posted another solution that implements WebApplicationInitializer and is called much before any spring bean is instantiated, in case someone has that use case

[Initialize default Locale and Timezone with Spring configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416955/initialize-default-locale-and-timezone-with-spring-configuration/26647966#26647966)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@EventListener` on your component, which will be invoked after the server is started and all beans initialized.

```
@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

For a file `StartupHousekeeper.java` located in package `com.app.startup`,

Do this in `StartupHousekeeper.java`:

```
@Component
public class StartupHousekeeper {

  @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
  public void keepHouse() {
    System.out.println("This prints at startup.");
  }
}
```

And do this in `myDispatcher-servlet.java`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.startup" />

</beans>
```