# Calling A Method After all SpringBeans and ApplicationContext have been initialized

Tags: java, spring

I have a method in a complex java program that needs to be called immediately after the web ApplicationContext and SpringBeans have been initialized.

I've tried toying around with 
`<bean id="..." class="..." init-method="initialize">` 
but this method will call a `applicationContext.get().getBean(beanId);` method.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may catch a [`ContextRefreshedEvent`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) with `ApplicationListener`.

Answer (score 24):

In Spring 4.2 onwards you can attach event listeners to Springs Lifecycle events (and your own) using annotations.  Simple add the @EventListener to a method and include the event type as the first (and only) parameter and Spring will automatically detect it and wire it up.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Easier than creating a bean

Comment: one of the best solution

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ApplicationListener<E>` for this purpose. In the generic type parameter you could use `ContextRefreshedEvent` for you requirement. And keep note that, in the overridden method `onApplicationEvent` you can do anything like autowire a bean or use it as a service or call another service from here. And note that how its different from `@PostConstructor`

```
public class MyContextRefreshListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors) which has access to the bean in question.

Comment: Doesn't BeanFactoryPostProcessor execute *before* all beans have been initialized?

Comment: Yes, `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is  _before_ all of the beans have been initialized.