# catch moment when spring initialized all beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, listener, interceptor

I have spring application(I haven't lazy beans).

I want to insert logic to place when all @Component(@Repositoey @Service @Controller) beans are initialized.

How can I make it?

Comment: Can't you use @ PostConstruct annotation on method e.g. @ PostConstruct
 private void init(){ ?

Comment: I need  invoke method after **ALL BEANS**

Comment: Take a look at my answer, this solution lets you execute any code after each bean is initialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling A Method After all SpringBeans and ApplicationContext have been initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409605/calling-a-method-after-all-springbeans-and-applicationcontext-have-been-initiali)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409605), you could use ApplicationListener and look for the [ContextRefreshedEvent](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events):

```
public class Loader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
                 // whatever you want to do when app context is initialized or refreshed
        }
}
```