# How to execute code after all spring content is initialized?

Tags: java, spring

I want to create some info logging to console when all `spring` content is initialized.

This includes all `@Autowired` dependencies resolved, all properties injected, and all `@PostConstruct` methods finished.

That's also why I can't use `@PostConstruct` here, as the order of multiple post annotations cnanot be guaranteed.

So, how could I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [catch moment when spring initialized all beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541600/catch-moment-when-spring-initialized-all-beans)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer now:

```
public class Loader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
                 // TODO
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly create and start the Application context then you can run code when the context initialization is complete.  The code would look like:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:path/to/spring/context.xml");
LOGGER.info("Initializing Spring context...");
appContext.start();
LOGGER.info("Spring context initialization complete.");
```