# Quartz one time job on application startup

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to integrate a Quartz job in my spring application. I got this example from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/). The example shows jobs executing at repeated intervals using a `simpletrigger` and at a specific time using a `crontrigger`.

My requirement is to run the job only once on application startup. I removed the property `repeatInterval`, but the application throws an exception :

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Repeat Interval cannot be zero
```

Is there any way to schedule a job just once ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564361/scheduling-tasks-to-run-once-using-the-spring-task-namespace)

Ignoring the `repeatInterval` and setting `repeatCount = 0` does what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Spring *SimpleTriggerFactoryBean* does the job: if you don't specify the start time, it will set it to 'now'.

Yet I think that long-running one-time job should be considered an anti-pattern, since it will not work even in 2-node cluster: if the node that runs the job goes down, there will be no one that would restart the job.

I prefer to have a job that repeats e.g. every hour, but annotated with *@DisallowConcurrentExecution*. This way you guarantee that precisely one job will be running, both when the node that originally hosted the job is up, and after it goes down.