# Spring hook when all ApplicationContexts are finished refreshing?

Tags: java, spring

I have initialization code that I want to run after Spring has refreshed *all* `ApplicationContext`s.

Right now I have an instance of `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` that listens for when my contexts are done, but it gets called for every context in my application.

How can I listen for the very last one?

I've tried to listen for the root using `event.getApplicationContext().getParent() == null` but this is not the last context to load.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** This doesn't work; keeping the answer here for posterity.

I'm using the Spring scheduler for this; it seems to be the only thing that starts after Spring is really and truly finished loading.  (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18272697/295797) for reference):

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="someScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="foo" method="bar"
        initial-delay="1" fixed-rate="#{ T(java.lang.Long).MAX_VALUE }" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```