# How would I programmatically add a timezone to @Scheduled?

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

Spring wonderfully [offers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930171/provide-time-zone-to-spring-scheduled) a `zone` attribute to the `@Scheduled` annotation.  I am looking to provide the `@Scheduled` method with a time zone programmatically.

For example, say I want to turn the lights on at buildings in LA and Chicago, both at midnight local time.  I want to get the buildings from my repository.

Can the time zone be provided at runtime or otherwise injected?

Like:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *", zone = {THE_ZONE}) //midnight
public void myScheduledMethod() {       
     //...      
     building.toggleLights();  //could be LA or Chicago
}
```

I know that the `@Scheduled` method can't take any arguments, so providing the time zone that way won't do it.

Comment: Something like `zone = "${zone.property}"` should do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't that pull from a .properties file?  Would you mind posting an answer?  Not sure I follow.

Comment: No it will use a `PropertyResolver` which should delegate to the `Environment`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a value expression.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *", zone = "${zone.property}") //midnight
public void myScheduledMethod() { ... }
```

This will use the `Environment` to lookup the property named `zone.property` which can be set as en environment variable, read from a properties file etc.

If you want to retrieve them, as you state from the db, you would have to manually schedule the methods and not use the `@Schedule` method. Create a bean that at startup reads from the DB and registers the tasks with a `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: Exactly, so I'd need to go the bean route and not use the simpler `@Scheduled` way.  Imagine you have hundreds of buildings in hundreds of cities...

Comment: That would be a single factory reading the schedules from a database and schedule them. Just create the beans based on the database information.