# Issue with cron expression in java spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron

I am running a job scheduler in spring boot application.

To execute job every 5 min, I am using below cron expression

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * *", zone ="EST").
```

This is working fine
But when I try to execute the same job at a specific time, for instance at 11:30 AM, I am using below cron expression

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 11 * * *", zone ="EST")
```

This is not working
I couldn't find any mistake w.r.t syntax. Please help if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: that expression looks good to me ? what do you mean not working ?

Comment: remove  zone ="EST" and try again

Comment: Not working means - the scheduled method did not execute at the specified time. When I removed zone="EST", it did execute, but I need to specify the time zone as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide time zone to Spring @Scheduled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930171/provide-time-zone-to-spring-scheduled)