# Groovy Meta Class Enhancements

Tags: spring, groovy

I am currently working in a spring application and using groovy for few tasks

I have written few groovy meta class enhancements that i want to use application wide, dont have any idea as to how they can made availaible application wide.

Any ideas

Answer (score 3):

Hook into the Spring container startup lifecycle (see [Execute method on startup in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring)) and apply your meta class changes.