# Groovy and Spring Integration with Maven

Tags: spring, jpa, groovy

I am attempting to run an application. I have gmaven so it can build. 
Basically, I am trying to run a script everytime the application starts where it parses and XML file and populates a database using the existing data access objects. I am unclear of where I should put the script etc. Has anyone had experience regarding this? Not sure if it's relevant, but the project I am working on uses JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Write a Groovy class, put it in some package below src/main/groovy, register it as a Spring bean, inject the DAO(s), and make sure that one of the methods of the Groovy class gets executed when the Spring container starts up (see [Execute method on startup in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring)). Essentially no difference to how you would do it in Java.