# Block of code that I need to run everytime my servlet container starts up

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have some static block of content which need to load on startup of Spring MVC application.

```
static{
    // Added to use in the Log4J.xml file
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.setProperty("current.date", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
```

This '`current.date`' property I am doing to use in the `log4j.xml` to set the current date.
I don't know where to put this into Spring's context so that It can call every time when user runs the application.

Comment: See the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring

Answer (score 1):

In the main bean, implement the `InitializingBean` interface. In this interface methods, put your above statements. *They will run before initializing the bean.*

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/coding/configure-log4j-for-creating-daily-rolling-log-files

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following:

1. Put this code in the `init()` of a Servlet.
2. Configure this servlet in `web.xml`.
3. You can decide the order of loading (`<load-on-startup/>`) this servlet relative to other servlets.
4. When the container loads, it initializes the servlet and calls its `init()` method executing the initialization code.