# How to start a thread inside spring container

Tags: multithreading, spring

Please help to resolve a problem. I have a thread like below the code.

```
public class A implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
     while(true) {
     //Do something something important
    }
  }
```

}

I want to configure this thread in spring configuration file in such a manner, so that when spring container gets started, the thread start running. It means I have to start the thread using th.start() in a class, but that will never be used. The thread should start without instantiating any bean from the container. It is not Timer task type functionality.

Comment: Put this under @PostConstruct follow the [LINK][1] for details


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring

Answer (score 2):

```
<bean class="java.lang.Thread" init-method="start">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="A"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This will create and start a thread, making the thread a bean. You could maybe use `destroy-method="interrupt"` to stop the thread when the container stops, but anything fancier would require support code. I recommend Guava's [AbstractExecutionThreadService](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutionThreadService.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

create one class which implements ApplicationListener and wire your thread start logic on oeverridden method of it .

Example :

```
            public class A implements Runnable {

                  public void run() {
                     while(true) {
                     //Do something something important
                    }
                  }

            }
                  public class B implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

                      @Override
                        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
                            Thread t = new Thread(new A());
                            t1.start()

                      }

                  }
```