# Run TimerTask on start Application Server

Tags: java, spring, timertask

I have a Timer class to response of SMS continuously.

```
public class MyRegularTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        answerLeftSMS();
        // this.cancel(); I do not cancel this Timer
    }
}
```

Currently I am running it by a action call.

```
Timer time = new Timer();
MyRegularTask taskTimer = new MyRegularTask();
time.schedule(taskTimer, 0, 60000);
```

Is there any way to run this timer automatically, when I start Application Server (Tomcat, Glassfish) ? I am using Spring MVC (Annotation).

Comment: Out of curiositiy: Why `Thread.sleep(1000);` ?

Comment: Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2401536/1638059

Comment: This can be accomplished using [`@Scheduled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html). For implementation details see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do the trick

```
@Component
public class MyRegularTask extends TimerTask {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Timer time = new Timer();
        MyRegularTask taskTimer = new MyRegularTask();
        time.schedule(taskTimer, 0, 60000);
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        answerLeftSMS();
        // this.cancel(); I do not cancel this Timer
    }
}
```