# Spring Data Repository Populator from CSV

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Would Spring Data Repository populator be able to pre load the databases using CSV data or what would be the best way to load CSV data in Spring Boot JPA repositories.

Comment: suppose you can write a method that populate the CSV data to the database on application start up using  you can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring) about `@PostConstruct` annotation

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a CommandLineRunner (assuming you're using Spring Boot)

I've put together a small gist here:
https://gist.github.com/jkupcho/a423bd26509adb08844642ad16e16115