# CommandLineRunner functionality in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, wildfly

We have a Spring MVC project with multiple Maven modules. We package it into an EAR and deploy it to a WildFly server.

I am trying to do a single time job on project start up. Thus, I thought about the CommandLineRunner interface, the project would compile and run but the commandLineRunner run method wouldn't run.

I guess it's because we are using an MVC Spring project and not a SpringBoot one with its own embedded server.
Can you suggest any ways to implement such a concept in Spring MVC ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer or other from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44239113/11733759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```java
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StartupExec implements {

  @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
  public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
    // do whatever you need here 
  }
}
```

This is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037758/11733759).

Comment: Thanks ! the pointed answer worked. Not the part you mentioned however but the updated version of it.