# How do I actually start a MongoDB Change Stream in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, watch, changestream

So I've managed to build up a very basic MongoDB Change Stream in my Spring Boot application:

```
public class MongoDBChangeStream {

    public void changeStream() {

        // connect to the local database server
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("db uri goes here");

        // Select the MongoDB database
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("MyDatabase");

        // Select the collection to query
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("teams");

        // Create pipeline for operationType filter
        List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.match(
                        Filters.in(
                                "operationType",
                                Arrays.asList("insert", "update", "delete")
                        )));

        // Create the Change Stream
        ChangeStreamIterable<Document> changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline)
                .fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP);

        // Iterate over the Change Stream
        for (ChangeStreamDocument<Document> changeEvent : changeStream) {
            // Process the change event here
            switch (changeEvent.getOperationType()) {
                case INSERT:
                    System.out.println("MongoDB Change Stream detected an insert");
                    break;
                case UPDATE:
                    System.out.println("MongoDB Change Stream detected an update");
                    break;
                case DELETE:
                    System.out.println("MongoDB Change Stream detected a delete");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm listening for ***inserts***, ***updates*** and ***deletes*** in the ***'teams'*** collection, and then just print out the appropriate message in the console.

But how do I actually start the listener? When I run the application, something needs to start the changeStream for it to start watching the collection.. How do I do that?

Comment: It should be started already when you envoke `.watch()`. Are you not seeing any results? Could you try without filters or options and debug from there? eg `collection.watch().forEach((Consumer<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>>) System.out::println);`

Comment: @dangarfield I understand, but the whole `changeStream` method needs to be invoked before `.watch()` is invoked, or am I completely wrong here? This is not my Main class, so I don't see when the `changeStream` method is ever invoked?

Comment: Is that not both the problem and the solution? I'll add a potential spring-boot-esque solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you be able to simply add a `@Configuration` class with a `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseChangeStreamInitialiser {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
      // eg, call `MongoDBChangeStream.changeStream`
    }
}
```

or

```
@Component
public class DatabaseChangeStreamInitialiser {

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void init() {
      // eg, call `MongoDBChangeStream.changeStream`
    }
}
```

There are many ways to do this, you can `@EventListener` annotations to listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent`. Create `InitializingBean`s, or even just finding the `main` method in your class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Some other options are documented here:
[Execute method on startup in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring)

Hopefully it is just that. If not, if you could describe the exact startup process and details of your spring-boot app, that would help.

Comment: That's exactly the thing I was looking for and it works. Thank you very much!!!